# Internet slow in terminal, but it gets faster when I enable a VPN

Tags: terminal, wifi, vpn, internet

### Whatever I do in my terminal (any terminal) on Arch (even using a live cd), that requires internet access, is painfully slow.

```
curl google.com
```

takes about 15 seconds to produce an output

```
wget -O /dev/null http://cachefly.cachefly.net/100mb.test
```

takes about 5 seconds to start downloading, then slowly climbs to 400kb/s and fluctuates there

```
speedtest-cli
```

awful pingtimes, and awful down/up speeds.

I've written some apps myself that parse some RSS feeds and another that get's my public IP, both of them take about 20-30 seconds to return.

[image]
As you can see, meanwhile my browser reaches my normal speeds

### But it's getting better, let me start my OpenVPN Client.

[image]

Now my speeds in the terminal are better! Still not equal to the browser, but better. The upload speed is even equal.

curl, wget, my apps, all return within a couple milliseconds too.

I'm beyond lost. Any ideas? This issue started to appear out of nowhere and is now persistent even after reinstalling the OS. On Windows the speeds are fine.

Tried a couple different kernels, no change either.

Comment: is the VPN thingy setting a DNS server that was broken somehow before?

Comment: Your provider is having issue with DNS, change them to openDNS for example: 208.67.222.222 and 208.67.220.220 and do the same test again

Comment: Also check the result of the command `tracepath 8.8.8.8` both in and out of your VPN, a routing issue could explain what your feeling currently

Comment: @Kiwy I'm using `1.1.1.1` and `1.0.0.1` with and without VPN. [link](https://imgur.com/a/tEzvNcd) <- tracepath
Edit: Changed to `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` -> No difference

Comment: what about `tracepath` ?

Comment: I've linked tracepath in my previous reply. If you're asking if it changed after setting the dns servers to google's, No. It didn't.